# E-Mail made in Germany. Better than traditional ones like Google or Yahoo?

Tags: email

A friend of my mine who lives in Germany called my attention to a so called "[E-Mail made in Germany](http://www.e-mail-made-in-germany.de/)" (EMiG). Since the country is well known for exporting high quality products, I decided to take a look at it.

The three main points they list as main features are:

> - Encrypted transmission (SSL)
> - Data processing in Germany (Compliant to German privacy regulations)
> - Visual icon to highlight "EMiG to EMiG" communications, which can obtained via app or MS Outlook plug-in.

Apart from the data processing in Germany, I don't see any difference to world biggest e-mail services out there like Yahoo! or Google, since both offer SSL too.

My friend asked me if he should change his e-mail address (which is currently a GMail) to a "Made in Germany" one. Would it really be much more secure or is it just a marketing thing?

Comment: @John can you back up that claim?

Comment: John - if you are in any location that has concerns over US spying on your email (ie most of the world) , then an email service meeting German privacy requirements is very definitely a security improvement.

Comment: @Schröder Sure, the Implementation has several design problems, but the advertisment creates the Impression  it would be End-to-End encryption, which isn't the case. If you speak german take a look at this article by the [CCC]( http://hannover.ccc.de/~nexus/whistle.html) or here by [Datenschutz]( https://www.datenschutzbeauftragter-info.de/e-mail-made-in-germany-datenschutz-oder-nur-marketing/). In the end you have to really trust the provider which is not a good Sec Model.

Comment: @Rory Well that isn't true per se. The german privacy laws do allow data access and analyzation by authorities. Just not in general or without a special purpose. If you take a look at the laws you may get the impression it would protect you against surveillance. You should take into consideration that the BND has tightly worked together with the NSA and that there are laws that do allow the BND do collect Emails. You are better of using PGP anyway if these are your concerns and perhaps use your own Mailserver.

Comment: Oh yes, I know all that - we have to deal with it regularly - but it gives far stronger controls than most countries.

Comment: Just now GMX and WEB.de have easy direct support for PGP through browser plugin [heise] (http://www.heise.de/newsticker/meldung/Web-de-und-GMX-fuehren-PGP-Verschluesselung-fuer-Mail-ein-2786133.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point to "Made in Germany" isn't about security, but about compliance to German privacy laws, which are unique.

It does not make those services more secure, but simply compliant to a specific set of privacy regulations.

Comment: It's not that bad: A federation of German email providers has agreed to use an encrypted channel to exchange emails between them. This adds security (not against NSA or BND, but surely against hackers in the dark).

Comment: I understand that, but is it different from Gmail's infrastructure? I'm not saying that it's bad at all, I'm just saying that there isn't increased security over services like Gmail.

Comment: See my comment on the question.

Comment: @RoryAlsop I'm splitting hairs on general security and enhanced privacy.

Comment: @schroeder As far as I know, when you send an email from e.g. gmail to e.g. yahoo, it goes over an open channel. Forming an email provider federation with secured channels is a big progress.

Comment: @jknappen SMTPTLS means that email even between providers is encrypted, like between Yahoo and Gmail: http://yahoo.tumblr.com/post/81529518520/status-update-encryption-at-yahoo